# how to use material ui icon v1.0.0-beta.36 in .tsx component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tsx

I'm using material-ui-icons v1.0.0-beta.36.

I'm trying to use a `Search` icon in a .tsx component.

`.tsx` component:

```
import React, { Component, ReactElement } from 'react'
import Search from 'material-ui-icons/Search'

import { Button, CustomInput } from '../thirdParty/CreativeTim/components'
import { ENTER_KEY_CODE } from '../../../Services/Constants'
import { SvgIconProps } from 'material-ui/SvgIcon'

let SearchIcon: ReactElement<SvgIconProps> = <Search />
```

[image]

Getting this error on the `<Search />` component:

```
JSX element type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | Component<...> | null' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'Component<SvgIconProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
    Type 'Component<SvgIconProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.ts(2605)
```

Also, tried using it without assigning the variable:

`.tsx` component:

```
import React, { Component, ReactElement } from 'react'
import Search from 'material-ui-icons/Search'

import { Button, CustomInput } from '../thirdParty/CreativeTim/components'
import { ENTER_KEY_CODE } from '../../../Services/Constants'
import { SvgIconProps } from 'material-ui/SvgIcon'

...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <Button
          onClick={this.onSearchclick}
          color="white"
          aria-label="edit"
          justIcon
          round
        >
          <Search />
        </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

Getting kind of a same error on the `<Search />` component:

```
JSX element type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | Component<...> | null' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'Component<SvgIconProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
    Type 'Component<SvgIconProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
      Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
        Type '() => ReactNode' is not assignable to type '{ (): ReactNode; (): false | Element | null; }'.
          Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.ts(2605)
```

Couldn't find anything online with a solution for that..

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Edit zealous-curran-xuyth]

Comment: Can add your code to codesandbox ?

Comment: @RichWarrior, I added codesandbox

Comment: I looked at the code and everything works fine

Comment: There is some problem using material-ui-icon with `.tsx` components. Probably related to the material-ui-icon old version i have. I managed to solve it by creating a `.jsx` "transition" component that calls the material-ui-icon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving that by declaring the icon with `any` type:

```
const SearchIcon: any = Search
```

and then use it as a regular component:

```
<SearchIcon />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to import it like this :

```
import {Search} from 'material-ui-icons/Search';
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve the problem. in fact, its not a legit import in this case.

Comment: try this library instead. sorry about the earlier comment. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons